# Pandas- Split dataset based on overlapping time periods

Tags: python, pandas

I have reporting time periods that start on Mondays, end on Sundays, and run for 5 weeks. For example:

```
11/20/2017 - 12/24/2017 = t1 
11/27/2017 - 12/31/2017 = t2
```

I have a dataframe that consists of 6 of these periods (starting 11/20/2017) and I'm trying to split it into 6 dataframes for each time period using the `LeaveDate` column. My data looks like this:

```
Barcode LeaveDate  
ABC123  2017-11-22 
ABC124  2017-12-04  
ABC125  2017-12-15
```

As the dataframe is separated, some of the barcodes will fall into multiple periods- that's OK. I know I can do:

```
df['period'] = df['LeaveDate'].dt.to_period('M-SUN')
df['week'] = df['period'].dt.week
```

To get single weeks, but I don't know how to definte a "multi-week" period. The problem also is that a barcode can full under multiple periods, so they need to be outputted to multiple dataframes. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use `{x: y for x, y in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='LeaveDate', freq='W-MON'))}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more succinct solution, but this should work (will give you a dictionary of DataFrames, one for each period):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['ABC123', '2017-11-22'],
                   ['ABC124',  '2017-12-04'],
                   ['ABC125',  '2017-12-15']],
                   columns=['Barcode', 'LeaveDate'])
periods = [('2017-11-20', '2017-12-24'), ('2017-11-27', '2017-12-31')]

results = {}
for period in periods:
    period_df = df[(df['LeaveDate'] >= period[0]) & (df['LeaveDate'] <= period[1])]
    results[period] = period_df
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Just realised reading it back that I forgot to define my empty dictionary in my example above. Will edit now in case anyone else is reading in future, although seems you worked that part out anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I put that in, but thanks for coming back and checking.

Comment: Hey, @thesilkworm just wondering, how could you return back the data in array format ...A 2d array for x and 1d array for y?...i